# Why does docker-compose build give me no such file or directory error message

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I want to setup a laravel dev environment using docker and docker-compose. And I cannot get my Dockerfile to build.

I have followed tutorials without success:

- https://github.com/BretFisher/php-docker-good-defaults
- https://dev.to/aschmelyun/the-beauty-of-docker-for-local-laravel-development-13c0
- https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-laravel-nginx-and-mysql-with-docker-compose

When I use `sudo docker exec -it php sh`
I log into the php instance and I am able to run composer install.

docker-compose.yml

```
  build:
    context: .
    dockerfile: Dockerfile
  container_name: php
  restart: unless-stopped
  tty: true
  volumes:
    - ./src:/var/www                                                                                                  
  ports:                                                                                                   
    - "9000:9000"                                                                                                 
  networks:                                                                                                   
    - laravel
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM php:7.0-fpm-alpine
WORKDIR /var/www
COPY composer.lock composer.json /var/www
```

Step 3/3 : COPY composer.lock composer.json /var/www/                                                                                ERROR: Service 'php' failed to build: COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder015559251/composer.lock: no such file or directory

Here is my directory structure when I terminal into the php instance.
[image]

Comment: in what folder  level is `composer.lock` on your host ?

Comment: I added a screenshot of the directory structure when I terminal into the php instance.

Comment: the file should be first in your host, then you can copy it . that what i mean

Comment: You need to add the files as @LinPy said. You can do this for example (copy everything with `$ ADD . .`

Comment: I think I misunderstand the difference between ADD and COPY.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anybody else lands up over here:

I had this line in my docker file:

```
COPY composer.lock composer.json /var/www
```

And it should have been:
'''
COPY src/composer.lock src/composer.json .
'''

Essentially your copy from path (first two arguments) is relative to the Dockerfile.
And the paste to path is relative to the WORKDIR, which was already set to /var/www.

I hope this helps, but please comment if there is anything I need to clarify.